# Add string to list of dfs in R

Tags: r

I have a list of dataframes with varying rows and columns.
Here is an example:

```
> df_input_list
[[1]]
   Feature    Method                              
1    Feat1  Variant1                                                   
2    Feat2  Variant2 

[[2]]
   Feature2  Method2 Attribute
1     Feat3 Variant3     Attr1
2     Feat4 Variant4     Attr2
3     Feat5 Variant5     Attr3
```

Now I want to add strings to the entire dataframes in a list with lengt *n*, however, with varying strings to the respective dfs. Like this:

```
> df_input_list
[[1]]
           Feature            Method                              
1    String1_Feat1  String1_Variant1                                                   
2    String1_Feat2  String1_Variant2 

[[2]]
          Feature2          Method2      Attribute
1    String2_Feat3 String2_Variant3  String2_Attr1
2    String2_Feat4 String2_Variant4  String2_Attr2
3    String2_Feat5 String2_Variant5  String2_Attr3
```

I tried `for` loops with `paste()`, but I can not figure out the correct way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `base R`

```
Map(\(x, i) {
 x[] <- paste0('String', i, as.matrix(x))
x
}
, df_input_list, seq_along(df_input_list))
```

Answer (score 1):

With `imap` (created a mock dataset first):

```r
library(purrr)
l <- list(head(cars), head(cars))

imap(l, \(x, y) map_dfr(x, \(z) paste0("String", y, "_", z)))
```

output

```r
[[1]]
# A tibble: 6 × 2
  speed     dist      
  <chr>     <chr>     
1 String1_4 String1_2 
2 String1_4 String1_10
3 String1_7 String1_4 
4 String1_7 String1_22
5 String1_8 String1_16
6 String1_9 String1_10

[[2]]
# A tibble: 6 × 2
  speed     dist      
  <chr>     <chr>     
1 String2_4 String2_2 
2 String2_4 String2_10
3 String2_7 String2_4 
4 String2_7 String2_22
5 String2_8 String2_16
6 String2_9 String2_10
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an option with `purrr::map2()` so you can use both the original list as `.x` and use `.y` as `seq_along(.x)` so you can also keep track of where you are in the list.

Note there are nested lambda functions that each use `.x` as the argument which works but may be confusing at first glance.

```r
library(tidyverse)

l <- list(
  tibble(
    feature = paste0("feature", 1:2),
    method = paste0("variant", 1:2)
  ),
  tibble(
    feature2 = paste0("feature", 3:5),
    method2 = paste0("variant", 3:5),
    attribute = paste0("attr", 1:3)
  )
)

l %>% 
  map2(.y = seq_along(.),
       ~mutate(.x, across(everything(), ~paste0("String", .y, "_", .x))))
#> [[1]]
#> # A tibble: 2 × 2
#>   feature          method          
#>   <chr>            <chr>           
#> 1 String1_feature1 String1_variant1
#> 2 String1_feature2 String1_variant2
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> # A tibble: 3 × 3
#>   feature2         method2          attribute    
#>   <chr>            <chr>            <chr>        
#> 1 String2_feature3 String2_variant3 String2_attr1
#> 2 String2_feature4 String2_variant4 String2_attr2
#> 3 String2_feature5 String2_variant5 String2_attr3
```

<sup>Created on 2022-09-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: That also leads to the right solution, however, I thought about a more flexible apporach, because the headers of the dfs are just examples.

Answer (score 0):

Double `for` loop solution.

```
s <- c('String1', 'String2')
for (i in seq_along(df_input_list)) {
  for (j in seq_along(df_input_list[[i]])) {
    df_input_list[[i]][[j]] <- paste(s[i], df_input_list[[i]][[j]], sep='_')
  }
}
df_input_list
# [[1]]
# Feature           Method
# 1 String1_Feat1 String1_Variant1
# 2 String1_Feat2 String1_Variant2
# 
# [[2]]
# Feature2          Method2     Attribute
# 1 String2_Feat3 String2_Variant3 String2_Attr1
# 2 String2_Feat4 String2_Variant4 String2_Attr2
# 3 String2_Feat5 String2_Variant5 String2_Attr3
```

---

*Data:*

```
df_input_list <- list(structure(list(Feature = c("Feat1", "Feat2"), Method = c("Variant1", 
"Variant2")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2")), 
    structure(list(Feature2 = c("Feat3", "Feat4", "Feat5"), Method2 = c("Variant3", 
    "Variant4", "Variant5"), Attribute = c("Attr1", "Attr2", 
    "Attr3")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", 
    "3")))
```